# Why do I need "&" in printf when I want to print a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

So I wrote this code where I scan 2 strings. One is declared as an array and one as a pointer.
Now to my question: Why do I need for printing text2 in the printf-statment the "&" before Text2 and when I print Text1 not?

I thought if I put "&" in printf before the variable it pirnts the memory address. I this case not, it prints the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char Text1[45];
    char *Text2;

    
    scanf("%s" , &Text1);
    printf("Text1: %s\n", Text1);

    scanf("%s" , &Text2);
    printf("Text2: %s\n", &Text2);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about that code, turn up the options until it does (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for gcc and clang).

Comment: And it is time to *read* `pointers` chapter in your favourite C book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get rid of the part dealing with `Text1` for the moment, and focus solely on `Text2`. That leaves us with something like this:

```cpp
    char *Text2;

    scanf("%s" , &Text2);
    printf("Text2: %s\n", &Text2);
```

You've declared `Text2` as a pointer, but you haven't initialized it to point to any available space. Then you pass the *address* of that pointer to `scanf`, and match it up with a format that tells `scanf` to read a string, and deposit it at the specified location, so instead of using the pointer as a pointer, `scanf` will try to use it as if it were an array of `char`.

To make this work sanely, we want to use the pointer as a pointer, and have it point at some available memory--and we want to tell `scanf` the size of that memory, so the user can't enter more data than we've provided space to store.

```cpp
#define MAXSIZE 128

char *Text2 = malloc(MAXSIZE);

scanf("%127s", Text2); // note lack of ampersand here

printf("%s\n", Text2); // Now we don't need an ampersand here either.
```

Comment: The field width in `scanf` needs to be one less than the receiving buffer size, to allow for the null terminator. The field width in a conversion specification is a number of characters in the input being scanned, not the number of bytes in the receiving buffer.

Comment: Jerry Coffin, Off-by-one.  Better as `malloc(MAXSIZE);` ... `scanf("%127s"...`

Answer (score 1):

`char Text1[45]` is an array of characters. The compiler will allocate 45 bites in a program memory for use by the program. The value of the bytes is not known at the moment. So, `scanf("%s" , Text1)` will put input chars into this memory, assuming that there are less than 44 of them, or it will override the program stack and possibly crash. To prevent from this issue, you should use something like `%44s`.

There is no need to use `&` in this case. It does not do much with the array declared in such a way. Therefore you do not need it in `printf("%s\n", Text1)`. But you can use it if you wish.

`char *Text2` declares a pointer variable. It means that the compiler allocates enough space to contain the pointer value. The value of the pointer is not defined at the moment, so it does not point anywhere. If you plan to use it with characters, you need to allocate space for them or assign the space in a different way. For example, `Text2 = malloc(45)` will allocate 45 bytes for use and set a pointer to those bytes. Or you can do `Text2 = Text1`, assigning address of the first byte of the *Text1* array as a pointer. This way the *Text1* array will be used as a byte storage.

As a result, `scanf("%s", Text2)` will use the pointer to access bytes, either allocated by malloc or in the Text1. Now you need to `printf("%s\n", Text2)`.

You should not use `&` on Text2. It will return an address of the pointer variable and not the address of the array of bytes. You need the latter. So print with &Text2 will return trash and could cause a crash.

BTW, if you used *malloc* it is a good idea to `free` the memory which was allocated if it is not needed  any longer: `free(Text2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is exhibiting undefined behavior and although it is mostly pointless to speculate about undefined behavior, it may be interesting to consider the following:

```
$ cat a.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char text1[128] = {0};
        char *text2;
        char text3[128] = {0};

        scanf("%44s" , &text2); /* Undefined behavior */
        printf("Text1: %s\n", text1);
        printf("Text3: %s\n", text3);
        return 0;
}
$ echo abcdefghijklmnopHelloWorld | ./a.out
bash: child setpgid (96724 to 96716): Operation not permitted
Text1: 
Text3: HelloWorld
```

The behavior shown above indicates that on my platform, the text that is being written to `&text2` is overwriting the value of `text3` (this is a stack overflow).  This is simply because (on my platform), the variables text2 and text3 are placed 16 bytes apart in the stack when the program executes.  To reiterate, the behavior of the code is undefined and the actual performance will vary greatly depending on where it is run, but despite mythical warnings about demons flying out of your nose it is not likely to cause any harm experimenting with it.